# Using package minted inside a multicol (multicol package)

Tags: multicol, minted

I'm trying to list some code (package **minted**) inside a multicol (package **multicol**).

### Example Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    This is a listing inside a multicolom:
    \begin{listing}
      \begin{minted}{sql}
        SELECT * FROM table1
      \end{minted}
      \caption{Some random SQL Query}
      \label{lst:sql}
    \end{listing}
  \end{multicols}

  This is a listing outside the multicolums:
  \begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}{sql}
      SELECT * FROM table2
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Some other random SQL Query}
    \label{lst:sql2}
  \end{listing}

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image: output]

### Question:

The first listing is missing, as you can see. When not using minted inside the listing environment the code shows up, but without the needed chaption/label.

How can I use the minted listing environment inside a multicol with labels and chaptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that a `listing` is a float, like `table` or `figure`, and floats aren't allowed inside the `multicol` environment. If you're happy to place the listing where you want it by hand, you can achieve the effect you're after by removing the `listing` environment, using the `caption` package, and changing `\caption` to `\captionof`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  This is a listing inside a multicolumn:
  \begin{minted}{sql}
    SELECT * FROM table1
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Some random SQL Query}
  \label{lst:sql}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you need the float facility, another option is to use the `listing*` environment instead. This, however, will set the listing across the whole page rather than in a single column, and also means that it will never appear on the page being typeset when the command is read (always on some subsequent page).